# What is the idiomatic way to write common code for a group of classes with identical methods, but not implementing the same interface?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I'm using an external library that provides tightly related classes (generated from some template), but unfortunately without a shared interface, e.g.

```
public class A {
    public UUID id();
    public Long version();
    public String foo();
    public String bar();
}

public class B {
    public UUID id();
    public Long version();
    public String foo();
    public String bar();
}

public class C {
    public UUID id();
    public Long version();
    public String foo();
    public String bar();
}

// ... and more: D, E, F, etc.
```

Given I have no influence over the external library, **what's the idiomatic way to write logic common to a group of classes that share the same method signatures (at least, for the methods being used by the common logic)?**

Currently I do one of three things, on a case-by-case basis:

1. I write helper methods that take the primitive results from each object, *e.g.*

   ```
   private static void myHelper(UUID id, Long version, String foo, String bar) {
     ...
   }
   ```

   This way I can "unpack" an object regardless of its type:

   ```
   myHelper(whatever.id(), whatever.version(), whatever.foo(), whatever.bar());
   ```

   But that can get very wordy, especially when I need to work with many members.
2. In the scenario where I'm only working with getters (*i.e.* only need to access current values of the objects), I've found a way to use mapping libraries like Dozer or ModelMapper to map A or B or C to my own common class, *e.g.*

   ```
   public class CommonABC {
     UUID id;
     Long version;
     String foo;
     String bar;
   }
   ```

   By playing with configuration, you can get these libraries to map all members, whether method or field, public or private, to your class, *e.g.*

   ```
   modelMapper.getConfiguration()
       .setFieldMatchingEnabled(true)
       .setFieldAccessLevel(Configuration.AccessLevel.PRIVATE);
   ```

   But this was kind of a "broadsword" approach, a hack that IMO isn't clearly justified merely to factor out duplicate code.
3. Finally, in certain other scenarios it was most succinct to simply do

   ```
   private static void myHelper(Object extLibEntity) {
     if (extLibEntity instanceof A) {
       ...
     } else if (extLibEntity instanceof B) {
       ...
     } else if (extLibEntity instanceof C) {
       ...
     } else {
       throw new RuntimeException(...);
     }
   }
   ```

   It's obvious why this is bad.

In enterprise situations where you have to live with a library that is this way, what would you do?

I'm leaning toward writing a very explicit, if verbose, mapper (not using a generic mapper library) that translates these entities from the start. But, I wonder if there's a better way. (Like, is there a way to "cast" an object as implementing a new interface, in runtime?)

Comment: Have you thought about creating your interface and implementing it for each POJO, and at the same time each would implement also the original interface-less POJO? Depending on how you use them and how they are used in the library they come from, it might help.

Comment: @Norcino : *...but unfortunately without a shared interface...*, *Given I have no influence over the external library...*

Comment: This might be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49947749/how-to-create-an-interface-around-classes-that-already-exist-but-cannot-be-modif/49947805#49947805) question, but I think you will not find its answers satisfying.

Comment: the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56000354/3591273) points to right direction, alternatively you can try sth like the bridge pattern or similar design patterns (eg facade)

Comment: @NikosM. The bridge/facade approaches IMHO can become ugly when there are "many" methods and "many" classes implementing these methods: You basically have to create a delegator for *each* method and *each* class, generating a sh!tload of boilerplate code. I think that dynamic proxies *can* be a solution, given that there is no (other, language-level) mechanism for generic method delegation in Java...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option that is (under the hood) likely similar to the second approach, but comparatively lean and flexible, is to use [Dynamic Proxy Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html). With only a few lines of code, you can let any object "appear" to implement a certain interface, as long as it has the required methods. The following is an MCVE that shows the basic approach:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;
import java.util.UUID;

public class DelegatingProxyExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        C c = new C();

        CommonInterface commonA = wrap(a);
        CommonInterface commonB = wrap(b);
        CommonInterface commonC = wrap(c);

        use(commonA);
        use(commonB);
        use(commonC);
    }

    private static void use(CommonInterface commonInterface) {
        System.out.println(commonInterface.id());
        System.out.println(commonInterface.version());
        System.out.println(commonInterface.foo());
        System.out.println(commonInterface.bar());
    }

    private static CommonInterface wrap(Object object) {
        CommonInterface commonInterface = (CommonInterface) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
            CommonInterface.class.getClassLoader(), 
            new Class[] { CommonInterface.class }, new Delegator(object));
        return commonInterface;
    }

}

// Partially based on the example from
// https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html
class Delegator implements InvocationHandler {

    private static Method hashCodeMethod;
    private static Method equalsMethod;
    private static Method toStringMethod;
    static {
        try {
            hashCodeMethod = Object.class.getMethod("hashCode", (Class<?>[]) null);
            equalsMethod = Object.class.getMethod("equals", new Class[] { Object.class });
            toStringMethod = Object.class.getMethod("toString", (Class<?>[]) null);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new NoSuchMethodError(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private Object delegate;

    public Delegator(Object delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method m, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        Class<?> declaringClass = m.getDeclaringClass();

        if (declaringClass == Object.class) {
            if (m.equals(hashCodeMethod)) {
                return proxyHashCode(proxy);
            } else if (m.equals(equalsMethod)) {
                return proxyEquals(proxy, args[0]);
            } else if (m.equals(toStringMethod)) {
                return proxyToString(proxy);
            } else {
                throw new InternalError("unexpected Object method dispatched: " + m);
            }
        } else {

            // TODO Here, the magic happens. Add some sensible error checks here!
            Method delegateMethod = delegate.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(
                m.getName(), m.getParameterTypes());
            return delegateMethod.invoke(delegate, args);
        }
    }

    protected Integer proxyHashCode(Object proxy) {
        return new Integer(System.identityHashCode(proxy));
    }

    protected Boolean proxyEquals(Object proxy, Object other) {
        return (proxy == other ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE);
    }

    protected String proxyToString(Object proxy) {
        return proxy.getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(proxy.hashCode());
    }
}

interface CommonInterface {
    UUID id();

    Long version();

    String foo();

    String bar();
}

class A {
    public UUID id() {
        return UUID.randomUUID();
    }

    public Long version() {
        return 1L;
    }

    public String foo() {
        return "fooA";
    }

    public String bar() {
        return "barA";
    }
}

class B {
    public UUID id() {
        return UUID.randomUUID();
    }

    public Long version() {
        return 2L;
    }

    public String foo() {
        return "fooB";
    }

    public String bar() {
        return "barB";
    }
}

class C {
    public UUID id() {
        return UUID.randomUUID();
    }

    public Long version() {
        return 3L;
    }

    public String foo() {
        return "fooC";
    }

    public String bar() {
        return "barC";
    }
}
```

Of course, this uses reflection internally, and should only be used when you know what you're doing. Particularly, you should add some sensible error checking, at the place that is marked with `TODO`: There, the method of the interface is looked up in the given delegate object.

Answer (score 3):

The only technique not tried:

```
package aplus;

public interface Common {
    ...
}

public class A extends original.A implements Common {
}

public class B extends original.B implements Common {
}
```

Comment: I think this is the only sensible way to go, unless the library can be configured to add a base class.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the usage? If I create a helper method that takes a `Common` as a parameter, I still couldn't pass in an instance of `original.A`... Wouldn't I have to cast it to the child class `A`?

Comment: You cannot cast it, but you can add a constructor to each child class that accepts its respective parent class.

Comment: `aplus.A` evidently should have also a "copy" constructor for `original.A`. If the library also delivers `original.A` instances. In that case however I would tend to a more radical byte code refactoring or such, `ASM` or others should be able to create a copy where interfaces are implemented.

Comment: This case reminds me of JPA where entities are generated. In that case one could use inheritane to some degree.

Comment: Just want to make sure I fully understand. Let me call _your_ A, newA, to avoid confusion. So, we have `public class newA extends original.A implements Common {`. Now say I have `private static void myHelper(newA a) {`. I can't just call `myHelper(originalA);`, and you're saying I can't cast it. Then, would the correct usage be, `myHelper(new A(originalA));`? Sorry if I'm missing something obvious. Relatively new to Java.

Comment: Yes, `NewA newA = NewA(a); ...` would be the solution for the case one has only the orinal A instance `a`.

Comment: I still cannot imagine how this should work. Assuming that you are receiving an `OriginalA`  instance, and want to use it as a `Common` instance, you *can* do this `NewA extends OriginalA implements Common` thing, but *still* have to override all methods in `NewA` so that they delegate to the `originalA` instance that was given in the constructor, right? (Otherwise: Could you extend your answer to an [MCVE]?)

Comment: @Marco13 The IDE can generate all the delegator calls, otherwise generate all super methods, and replace `super.` to `delegate.`. However I intended to rather **not delegate**, but **copy** all fields from A to the NewA instance in the "copy" constructor of NewA. I want all logic to be on the NewA level/layer. With the need for copying rarer than its access (interface usage). For the reverse a dynamic proxy would be better.

Comment: Then this makes the assumption that the instances can sensibly created by just setting a few field values, and that all fields are accessible accordingly (roughly speaking: That the objects are like POJOs...). Even then, for "many" classes and "many" methods this would imply a considerable amount of boilerplate code...

Comment: Yes, and must be maintained when an original class changes.