# How can common resusable code be written?

Tags: java

```
private ErrorInfo mapErrorInfoTrade(com.Model.Trade trade) {
    ErrorInfo errorInfo = new ErrorInfo();
    errorInfo.setErrorCode(trade.getErrorCode());
    errorInfo.setErrorDate(trade.getErrorDate());
    return errorInfo;
}
    
private ErrorInfo mapErrorInfoContact(com.Model.Contact contact) {
    ErrorInfo errorInfo = new ErrorInfo();
    errorInfo.setErrorCode(contact.getErrorCode());
    errorInfo.setErrorDate(contact.getErrorDate());
    return errorInfo;
}
    
private ErrorInfo mapErrorInfoEmail(com.Model.Email email) {
    ErrorInfo errorInfo = new ErrorInfo();
    errorInfo.setErrorCode(email.getErrorCode());
    errorInfo.setErrorDate(email.getErrorDate());
    return errorInfo;
}
    
mapEmail(){
    mapErrorInfoEmail(email)
}

    
mapContact(){
    mapErrorInfoContact(contact)
}

mapTrade(){
    mapErrorInfoTrade(trade)
}
```

com.Model.Trade, com.Model.Contact, com.Model.Email cannot be modified that are being used from some outside jar.

I tried with the following code, but still not exactly able to make it work. If someone can help me on that.

```
private ErrorInfo mapErrorInfo(Object mapObject) {
    Object error = null;
    
    if(mapObject instanceof com.Model.Trade){
        error = (com.Model.Trade) mapObject;
    }
    if(mapObject instanceof com.Model.Contact){
        error = (com.Model.Contact) mapObject;
    }
    if(mapObject instanceof com.Model.Email){
        error = (com.Model.Email) mapObject;
    }
    
    ErrorInfo errorInfo = new ErrorInfo();
    errorInfo.setErrorCode(error.getErrorCode());   //because this error type is Object, error.getErrorCode() is not allowed
    errorInfo.setErrorDate(error.getErrorDate());   // same as above reson, its not allowed
    
    return errorInfo;
}
```

How can common resusable code be written?

Comment: Are you sure `Trade`, `Contact` and `Email` don't implement a common interface? If not ask the vendor to make it so or find a better vendor.

Comment: pss the errorCode and errorDate as parameters to a method that builds the ErrorInfo object

Comment: Yes, these are three different class that used has same ErrorInfo class refered
@FedericoklezCulloca

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to create an interface around classes that already exist but cannot be modified in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49947749/how-to-create-an-interface-around-classes-that-already-exist-but-cannot-be-modif)

Answer (score 3):

First check if those classes implement a common interface or have a common superclass, which declares those methods. If there is, use this parent as parameter for your method.

```
private ErrorInfo mapErrorInfo(CommonParent parent) {
  ErrorInfo errorInfo = new ErrorInfo();
  errorInfo.setErrorCode(parent.getErrorCode());
  errorInfo.setErrorDate(parent.getErrorDate());
  return errorInfo;
}
```

If there isn't, use an abstraction of your own, let's say:

```
public interface Error {

  String getErrorCode();
  String getErrorDate();
}
```

Make implementations for the classes you need:

```
public class TradeError implements Error {

  private final Trade trade;

  //constructor

  @Override
  public String getErrorCode() {
    return trade.getErrorCode();
  }

  @Override
  public String getErrorDate() {
    return trade.getErrorDate();
  }
}
```

Make similar implementations for `Contact` and `Email` and change your method to work with `Error`:

```
private ErrorInfo mapErrorInfo(Error error) {
  ErrorInfo errorInfo = new ErrorInfo();
  errorInfo.setErrorCode(error.getErrorCode());
  errorInfo.setErrorDate(error.getErrorDate());
  return errorInfo;
}
```

Example usage:

```
ErrorInfo ei = mapErrorInfo(new TradeError(trade));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can go with your own extractor interface and then some factory small methods to create wrappers for the existing classes.

```
interface ErrorInfoAccessor {
  String getErrorCode();
  String getErrorDate();
}
// use common interface for creating the info
public ErrorInfo mapError(ErrorInfoAccessor extractor) {
  ErrorInfo errorInfo = new ErrorInfo();
  errorInfo.setErrorCode(extractor.getErrorCode());
  errorInfo.setErrorDate(extractor.getErrorDate());
  return errorInfo;
}

enum ErrorInfoAccessors {
  ;

  // wrap any other class into the new interface
  public static <T>ErrorInfoAccessor fromMethods(T object, Function<T, 
String> getCode, Function<T, String> getDate) {
    return new ErrorInfoAccessor(T object) {
      public String getErrorCode() {
        return getCode.apply(object);
      }
      public String getErrorDate() {
        return getDate.apply(object);
      }
  }

  // sample utility method for Trade, same for the other two classes
  public static ErrorInfoAccessor fromTrade(Trade t) { 
    return fromMethods(t, Trade::getErrorCode, Trade::getErrorDate);
  }
}
```

You can use that for your classes by

```
ErrorInfo info = mapError(ErrorInfoAccessors.fromTrade(yourTrade));
```

Comment: @NoorusKhan you should also look into mapstruct which would allow you to define a simple single interface for mapping your classes' data into the `ErrorInfo`.

Answer (score -1):

no man, that's no what' intended with reusable code.
Reusable code is intended to reuse exactly the same code for the same behavior.
If tomorrow you have to add another entity with same fields, you have to change your function, and that's not reusable.

For this purpose, inheritance, abstract classes, and interfaces were born.

That's a small example of reusing code with inheritance:

```
@Getter @Setter
class BaseModel {
    private String errorCode;
    private LocalDate errorDate;
}

class Contact extends BaseModel {
    // other fields and methods
}

class Mail extends BaseModel {
    // other fields and methods
}

class Trade extends BaseModel {
    // other fields and methods
}

@Getter @Setter
class ErrorInfo {
    private String errorCode;
    private LocalDate errorDate;
}

public class ModelService {
    public ErrorInfo mapErrorInfo(BaseModel baseModel) {
        ErrorInfo errorInfo = new ErrorInfo();
        errorInfo.setErrorCode(baseModel.getErrorCode());
        errorInfo.setErrorDate(baseModel.getErrorDate());

        return errorInfo;
    }
}
```

With this approach, you can use `mapErrorInfo` for each class extends `BaseModel` without specify any class behavior.

Obviously, inheritance is so dangerous and must be used carefully, to avoid complex nested code. Best practice is a balance mix between inheritance, abstract classes, and interfaces.

Comment: OP cant modify the original classes because it is vendor code

Comment: "inheritance is so dangerous and must be used carefully" that's a tad overblown. True, inheritance can cause complexity and composition should be preferred, but calling it "dangerous" is a bit of an exaggeration.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I deliberately overblown, I still have PTSD :D